# B64 String Being Stripped From HttpService JSON Object Flex 4.0

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, base64

I am trying to decode some b64 images obtained from a web service in my Flex application.  The response of this web service is a basic JSON object, with a property (B64Image) that contains the encoded string.  The service works fine from my regular browser, however the b64 
string gets stripped.  So the object the result handler gets has a null value for B64Image.  Anyone see something wrong here?

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
{
  "PropertyPhotos": [
    {
      "B64Image": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD....etc"
    }
  ]
}  

<s:HTTPService id="photoService"
                       url="http://localhost/dev/photohandler.ashx"
                       resultFormat="text"
                       result="photoService_resultHandler(event)"
                       fault="photoService_faultHandler(event)">
        </s:HTTPService>
```

Answer (score 1):

it's difficult to see, what could be wrong here, because such a few code...

what does the debugger say? does anything come back from the webservice? is the result or fault event thrown?

Comment: The Flex result handler receives a JSON string representing the PropertyPhotos array as shown above, but there is no value for property B64Image.  No errors are thrown.  When I test in a regular browser, the JSON object is complete, i.e. property B64Image has the base64 encoded string.

Comment: so, the value is empty? have you tried to send a valua manually? just some characters to see if at least anything comes through?